# CSS sprite animation looks a bit jerky

Tags: css

I have a sprite made of 25 frames for a total width of 3427px and a css code like:

http://codepen.io/AlexanderWeb00/pen/aBKVaR

```
.test {
  width: 138px;
  height: 224px;
  background: url(/img/flame.png) no-repeat;
  animation: flame 2s steps(25) infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

@keyframes flame {
  100% {
    background-position: -3427px 0;
  }
}
```

each frame including 1px space on each side makes its width 138px.

It is it the case that I should add more frames or is there anything that cab be added with CSS?

Comment: add your image on jsfiddle and link the example.

Comment: yep you'll need to step through each frame

Comment: isn't step(25) already doing that?

Comment: @Alex 25 * 138 != 3427 and so there is obviously something wrong. Please create a demo or atleast upload the sprite and give us the link.

Comment: this is wha tI have used: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/sprite_sheet_animations_using_only_css.htm and it states to use the full width of the sprite

Comment: @Alex: With the information given in question, I can only say that there is something wrong (which you already know). The linked website is not wrong but we need to see the sprite or the demo to debug it. It is impossible to debug based on whatever has been provided so far. I'd understand if you have some legal or copyright restrictions but unfortunately there is no other way to debug this.

Comment: Ok i will upload asap

Comment: codepen link: http://codepen.io/AlexanderWeb00/pen/aBKVaR

Comment: The sprite has 25 frames with a total width of 1280px and this means each frame is roughly 51.2px. Given the rounding off logic used by each browser (and how it varies between browsers), I don't think you can get a proper jerk free animation with this sprite. My advice would be to give each frame a round number space. The best you could achieve here would be something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JEyjRz)